# Fedora VM not connecting to Host-Only

Tags: vmware-player, fedora20

Host: Win7, 
VM: Fedora 20, 
VMware player 7. 
Hello, I have been working on a virtual Fedora 20 OS for a while and randomly the connection dropped. The Wifi on the Host machine is fine, but the vm cannot connect. Here is the output for ifconfig -a:

```
eno16777736: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:3b:a0:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 19  base 0x2000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 480  bytes 75417 (73.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 480  bytes 75417 (73.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I don't have much experience with troublshooting on a linux OS. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding NM_CONTROLLED=yes to the network card config file located in etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. After which I then ran the command 
`sudo ifup <name of vm NIC>`